# how to achieve interface segregation with polymorphic behavior c++

Tags: c++, oop, interface

Suppose you have two functions `fun1` and `fun2`. there are two classes `der1` and `der2`. Both `der1` and `der2` implement `fun1`, but only `der2` implements `fun2`. But i need to have polymorphic behavior with a `base` pointer to both `der1` and `der2`. Does it make sense to have both these function in a base class (Abstract) even though only `der2` will use both?

`der1` and `der2` are related and I think `der2` should contain `der1`. But even then the base class will need to declare both `fun1` and `fun2`. How do I achieve ISP? Does below code looks fine or is there a way to restructure it in a better way?

```
class base // Abstract
{
public:
virtual void fun1() {//default implementation}    
void fun2(){ // used by only der2}
};

class der1 : public base
{
//this also have fun2 as its defined in base.
}

class der2 : public base
{
// should implement fun1 and fun2 both 
public:
void fun2() { //implements fun2.}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Interface Segregation Principle addresses the problem of client functions or classes using only a subset of all the methods in an interface they depend on. For example, imagine the following case:

[image]

In this case, both "Client" classes depend on the whole "BigInterface" API while they only really need a subset of methods. The simplest solution in a case like this is to "split" the big interface and create cohesive ones, e.g. :

[image]

In your particular case, it depends on who uses `der1`, `der2` and `base`. It is hard to know if your code *looks fine* without more context information, but **assuming that your client classes depend on `base` even though they only need either `fun1` or `fun2`**, you should apply a similar recipe as in the example and split your interface in two.

Hope that it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. the problem in splitting the interface is that i won't be able to use base pointer polymorphically if my base class doesnt have both fun1 and fun2..
der1 & der2 inherits base. If i segregate interfaces like say
 class der1interface{ void fun1();
} ;
class der2-interface {void fun1();
void fun2();
};
class base :  public combined_interface {}; // will have fun2 not needed by der1 class.
class der1 : public der1_interface {};// not polymorphically related to der1
class der2 : public der2_interface {};   // not polymorphically related to der1

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't make sense to have both functions in one base class, if there is a derived class which doesn't implement both functions. That would fail the Liskov Substitution Principle.

I suggest a hierarchy of interfaces:

```
struct base1
{
    virtual void fun1();
};

struct base2 : public base1
{
    virtual void fun2();
};

class der1 : public base1
{
public:
    virtual void fun1() override;
};

class der2 : public base2
{
public:
    virtual void fun1() override;
    virtual void fun2() override;
};
```

A `base1*` can point to either a `der1` or a `der2`, and therefore only has `fun1`.

A `base2*` has both `fun1` and `fun2`, and therefore can only point to a `der2`.